# window.history.replaceState is not replacing browser history list

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, replace, browser-history

I am using `window.history.replaceState` to replace URL from new URL and it working fine partially.

When someone goes to `example.com/?&test=123`, it will replace URL with `example.com/?` and back button not taking to previous URL (Back button working fine)

But when i see history tab in browser (chrome or firefox), i can see two history created one with `example.com/?&test=123` and another is `example.com/?` but it suppose to have only one entry `example.com/?`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         var url = window.location.href;
            var newUrl = url.replace(/&test=[^&]*/, '');
            window.history.replaceState({}, '', newUrl);    
</script>
```

How can i change browser history list/tab data?

Comment: Remove your code, test again, you'll probably see *two* example.com/?&test=123.   *"How can I change browser history"* - using the code you've provided.

Comment: @freedomn-m above code is not working as expected. it creating two history.

Comment: It worked for me, using your code with minor adjustments to match my test page.  I assume your `newUrl =` works otherwise you wouldn't see example.com/?.  If you add a second window.history.replaceState, then do you get 3?  Or still only two?   The only part that I can't see is how you're testing it.

Comment: @freedomn-m what is that changes you made. 

**I am testing by checking browser history in chrome.**

Answer (score 1):

Above code should work. You can try `window.history.go(-1)`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = window.location.href;
    var newUrl = url.replace(/&test=[^&]*/, '');
    window.history.pushState({}, '', newUrl);
    window.history.go(-1);
</script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var url = window.location.href;
        var newUrl = url.replace(/&test=[^&]*/, '');
        window.history.replaceState({}, '', newUrl);
        window.history.go(-1);
</script>
```